# type argument is not within bounds of type-variable

Tags: java, stack

Hi Stack Overflow community ^_^

Basically, I am working with Stacks and converting from Infix to Postfix equations.
This is the error message showing on screen when I am trying to compile the Stack class:

```
Stack.java:5: error: type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
    private LinkedList<T> list;
                       ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class Stack
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class LinkedList
```

I am having real troubles trying to figure out this error but sadly I don't have a clue of what might be the problem. If I knew a little better I could have provided you with more info.

Thanks in advance for any comments and help!

Update: Here is my class...

```
package ListPkg; 

public class Stack<T> //    implements Comparable<Stack>>  
{ 
    private LinkedList<T> list; 

    public Stack()
    {
        this("list");
    }
    public Stack(String name)
    {
        list = new LinkedList(name);
    }
    public void push(T item)
    {
        list.insertAtFront(item);
    }
    public T pop()
    {
        list.removeFromFront();
    }
    public int lenghtIs()
    {
        return list.lengthIs();
    }
    public T peek()
    {
        return list.returnFirstNode();
    }
    public void print()
    {
        list.print();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems you have a class `LinkedList` declared as

```
class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {...}
```

but you're trying to use it in a class `Stack` declared as

```
class Stack<T> {
    private LinkedList<T> list;
    ...
}
```

The type variable `T` declared in `Stack` is completely unrelated to the type variable `T` in `LinkedList`. What's more, they are not compatible. `LinkedList` expects a type that is a sub type of `Comparable`, but `Stack` is giving it a type argument that has no bounds. The compiler cannot allow this.

Add appropriate bounds to your `Stack` class' type parameter

```
class Stack<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```