# Compile time error for generic type

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

Normally, in eclipse, I can run my code without any compilation error. However, with ant file, I have faced with `error: type argument Map is not within bounds of type-variable Type`. What is wrong with my ant file?

The code I take error;

```
[javac] class StratI implements Strat<Map> {
[javac]                                      ^
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Map<?,?> declared in interface Strat
[javac] 1 error
```

Ant - javac portion;

```
<target name="compile"  depends="init">
        <javac  compiler="javac1.7"
                destdir="${build.dir}/classes"
                source="1.7"
                target="1.7"
                includeantruntime="false"
                encoding="ISO-8859-1">

                <src    path="${src.dir}" />
                <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
</target>
```

Note: I have search Google for this error. I dont see any source which tells the real reason and shows how to solve it.

Comment: you normally don't implement a generic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t

Comment: @Reimeus yes it is in different package

Comment: @PaulBastide what is the meaning of "donot"? Should I never ever implement generic!?

Comment: It might help to not use raw type `Map` and to specify parameter type

Comment: Have you tried to implement `StratI` with the type-variable of `Strat`? e.g. `class StratI implements Strat<Map<?,?>>`. The error says it: `Map` is not within bounds of `Map<?,?>`. That's because Map is a raw type.

Comment: @Narmer Your solution fix the compile error but the real question; whenever I run my project with Eclipse run, it runs as expected, fine. But, whenever I run the same project with my ant, it gives this error. I have changed the code as you said, now no compile error but why eclipse has not emitted this error before. (Note, no compile error but code not runnable with java. I am looking reaseon...)

Comment: Usually Eclipse gives a warning when a raw type isn't parametrized, not an error (_Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized_) Did you get this warning?

Comment: @Narmer no I have not got any warning as you mentioned

Comment: @Hevan With all the premises it does show a warning. See my answer below.

Comment: Eclipse use ECJ, and Ant use Javac: difference are normal since they don't implements the thing the same way. Could post the definition of interface `Strat` ?

Comment: I got the same problem. It is because the ant script uses JavaC compiler whereas your code uses Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Strat` apparently starts

```
class Strat implements Strat<Map>
```

Obviously you cannot have a class that implements itself (since that's an interface; it appears that you have a name collision). Further it can't be generic if it isn't declared as having a parameter.

Since you have a generic interface in a different package (per your comment, *yes it is in different package*) you can explicitly use the full package to the interface - for example,

```
package com.example.interface;

// A generic Strat interface
interface Strat<T> {
}
```

Then the to implement it (you should probably pick a more descriptive name - maybe `IStrat<T>`) -

```
package com.example.impl;

class Strat implements com.example.interface.Strat<Map> {
}
```

or using `IStrat`

```
class Strat implements IStrat<Map> {
}
```

Comment: no, signature of strat is `public interface Strat<T extends Map<?,?>>`

Comment: To which `Strat` are you referring? In your question it clearly states `class Strat implements Strat<Map>`, here Elliott is refererring to that.

Comment: code is running with built-in eclipse run method; however, with ant, it emits compile error

Answer (score 0):

Map is a [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and, as stated in the error, [is not within bounds of type-variable `Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22650289/3735079) which is `T extends Map<?,?>`. Altough you are extending a "take whatever" map, it is still a specification of a raw type.

You should change the declaration of your `StratI` interface implementation in:

```
class StratI implements Strat<Map<?,?>>
```

or since you're extending

```
class StratI implements Strat<HashMap<?,?>>
```

or yet since it's an implementation

```
class StratI implements Strat<HashMap<Integer, String>>
```

---

**EDIT**

The fact that Eclipse doesn't show it as an error is that Eclipse doesn't show compile  errors for unparametrized raw types. It shows a warning instead:

```
public interface myIn<T extends Map<?,?>>{
   void foo();
}

public class myClass implements myIn<Map>{
 @Override
 public void foo() {}

}
```

Eclipse will underline `Map` whit the warning:

> `Map` is a raw type. References to generic type `Map<K,V>` should be
>   parameterized

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined your interface is wrong. Please go through java documentation.
The below piece of code would help.

```
public interface Start<T> {
    public void display();
}

public class StartI implements Start<Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Implement here");
    }

}
```